# Regex to remove extra spaces in a string in JS format

Tags: javascript, php, regex, whitespace

I have the following string.

```
$json = '
    insert: [
        { table:" abc",values:{id:1,text:" lorem ipsum "} },
        {   table  :  "cde "  ,  values   :   { id  : 2  , firstname  :  "lorem ipsum   dolor sit    " } } 
    ]
    ';
```

Already tried with the regex below, but the result was not expected.

```
$json = preg_replace('~\s{1,}~', '', $json);
```

And I like to have the return below

```
 {"insert": [{"table": "abc", "values": {"id": 1, "text": "lorem ipsum"}}, {"table": "cde", "values": {"id": 2, "text": "lorem ipsum dolor sit"}}]}
```

To then use the **json_decode()**

I hope I have been clear

**Update:**

I have the following string.

**Example:**

```
$json_string = '
    insert: [
        { table:" abc",values:{id:1,text:" lorem ipsum "} },
        {   "  table  "  :  "cde "  ,  "  values"   :   { id  : 2  , firstname  :  "lorem ipsum   dolor sit    " } } 
    ]
    ';
```

**I want the following output**

```
$json_replaced = '{"insert": [{"table": "abc", "values": {"id": 1, "text": "lorem ipsum"}}, {"table": "cde", "values": {"id": 2, "text": "lorem ipsum dolor sit"}}]}';
```

Comment: From where/how do you get `$json` value? I think this is probably [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work for you:

```
$json = '
    insert: [
        { table:" abc",values:{id:1,text:" lorem ipsum "} },
        {   table  :  "cde "  ,  values   :   { id  : 2  , firstname  :  "lorem ipsum   dolor sit    " } } 
    ]
';
$json = '{' . $json . '}';
$json = preg_replace(array('/ *\n */', '/(?<=[{,]) *([^\s:]+) *: */'),
                     array("", '"$1": '), $json);
echo $json; // converted json string
print_r(json_decode($json, true)); // decoded array
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/wfxDYK

**OUTPUT:**

```
{"insert": [{"table": " abc","values": {"id": 1,"text": " lorem ipsum "} },{"table": "cde "  ,"values": {"id": 2  ,"firstname": "lorem ipsum   dolor sit    " } }]}

Array
(
    [insert] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [table] =>  abc
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [text] =>  lorem ipsum 
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [table] => cde 
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [firstname] => lorem ipsum   dolor sit    
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: As you can see from output above it is working fine. But if your input Json is different than post it and I can debug tomorrow morning.

Comment: I had to make an improvement, but it has served me. If you can further improve the regex, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Glad to know it worked, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just run the following:

$json_string = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", "", $json_string);

Output is:

```
insert: [{ table:" abc",values:{id:1,text:" lorem ipsum "} },{"table":"cde ","values":{ id: 2, firstname:"lorem ipsumdolor sit" } }]
```

Comment: And if you want to clean up spacing between the quotes, just run a regex on that too, so no more than 2 lines of code.

Comment: I wrote this answer back in May, I ended up bumping into my own issue today - my answer worked correctly, the current one marked did not work.